# Running Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) bash on Emacs shell

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Well I have been trying to get the WSL to work with emacs shell using this defun:

```
(defun sdev/win-bash-shell ()
  "Run Linux Subsystem bash in shell mode."
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe"))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
```

The Error I get is `Process shell exited abnormally with code 255`.
I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to get this to work with emacs.

Comment: Check if 'env' is in your PATH (env is supposed to have been installed with the coreutils package, by default). The absence of 'env' has been known to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
which bash
```

does show the pathname of bash within a WSL shell.
It shows WSL uses normal linux pathnames.
In my case it shows

```
/bin/bash
```

which should replace the windows pathname

```
C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe
```

in your code snippet.